# C# - Remover ASPAS - Replace - Remover ASP Duplas

Tags: c#, string, replace

Possuo uma variável(TEXTO) que é uma string, onde seu valor é: "22/06/2018 00:00:00"
Como fazer uma Replace removendo sua aspas?

Comment: Essas aspas você está vendendo no debug ou no seu banco está assim mesmo?

Comment: @NetinhoSantos.. Desculpa.,salvando no meu banco!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx).  segue um exemplo: http://rextester.com/ZPYKJ63622

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     var x =  @"""22/06/2018 00:00:00""";
     var y = x.Replace("\"", " ");
     Console.WriteLine(y);
 }
```

Comment: Perfeito! Obg...